# Javascript scope and self=this, _this=this, that=this

Tags: javascript

Why is `_this.` not working but `this.` is working.

I thought the whole point of `_this=this` was to provide a mechanism for when object functions are called, you have a "guaranteed" reference back to the instantiated object as it is now within the closure of the object function to mimic traditional class behavior.  I've read so many pieces about scope and for some reason I'm just not seeing it.  What am I missing?

```
var PersonClass = function PersonClass(_name, _age) {
    _this=this;
    this.name=_name;
    this.age=_age;

    console.log("created "+this.name+":"+this.age);

    function changeAge(num) {
        console.log("changing age for:" + _this.name);
        _this.age=num;
    }

    PersonClass.prototype.changeAge=changeAge;
    PersonClass.prototype.getAge=function() { 
        console.log(_this.name+":"+_this.age);
        return _this.age;
    };
    PersonClass.prototype.getAge2=function() { 
        console.log(this.name+":"+this.age);        
        return this.age;
    };
};

// comments indicate what value is displayed in console
var john=new PersonClass("john",1);  // john:1
var sue=new PersonClass("sue",2);    // sue:2

john.getAge(); // sue:2
john.getAge2(); // john:1

john.changeAge(10); // sue
sue.getAge(); // sue:10
sue.getAge2(); // sue:10
john.getAge(); // sue:10
john.getAge2(); // john:1
```

Comment: Probably because you've not `var`d it. You're also doing something very unusual with the prototyping there. The way you've written it, these should be instance methods not inherited methods

Comment: this is a broken mish-mash of two different ways of writing "classes" in JS.

Comment: Don't use global variables, and don't capture locals in prototype methods.

Comment: Paul - that's not it.  var _this=this  doesn't change anything
Alnitak - how would you do it?
SLaks - What do you mean by "capture".

Comment: stop using prototype, simplest answer. Prototype is a very old way of doing this, and it is very unnecessary, clunky, and not easily manageable. Check my answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: @WebWanderer Using `prototype` has it's place. It's just not the best usage for this case...

Comment: @WebWanderer - I was thinking prototype was good for this case?  If we created a billion PersonClass records, isn't the benefit of prototype that the function isn't dumped in the global space for each instantiation? I've probably got that wrong also

Comment: Using `prototype` is frowned upon. A JS `object` always has its own set of built in properties, which can be found within `prototype`. Appending your own `prototype`s to an `object` have the chance of conflicting with these. You can append your own properties, maintain scope, and have no issue reaching those properties without `prototype`. And yes @War10ck `prototype` definitely has its place, just not here. You should only use `prototype` to modify an internal struct like `Object` or `String`, which is still frowned upon by most people, but can be pretty cool.

Comment: With this question out of the way, thought I'd take the three method suggestions and run a small performance test on them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937436/what-is-the-fastest-class-object-access-instantiation-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the `scope` of your internal functions is not being resolved to `this`, therefore, they lose all reference to the scope created at the instanciation of `new PersonClass()`. The `bind` method will resolve the `scope` of the internal functions to `this` of the parent function class.

```
var PersonClass = function PersonClass(_name, _age)
{
    var _this=this;
    this.name=_name;
    this.age=_age;

    console.log("created "+this.name+":"+this.age);

    this.changeAge = function(num)
    {
        console.log("changing age for:" + _this.name);
        _this.age = num;
    }.bind(this);

    this.getAge = function()
    { 
        console.log(_this.name+":"+_this.age);
        return _this.age;
    }.bind(this);

    this.getAge2 = function()
    { 
        console.log(this.name+":"+this.age);        
        return this.age;
    };
};

// comments indicate what value is displayed in console
var john = new PersonClass("john",1);  // john:1
var sue = new PersonClass("sue",2);    // sue:2

john.getAge(); // sue:2
john.getAge2(); // john:1

john.changeAge(10); // sue
sue.getAge(); // sue:10
sue.getAge2(); // sue:10
john.getAge(); // sue:10
john.getAge2(); // john:1
```

Yup, that'll do it.

Hey look, it works! [**Here's the updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w20rtmqn/4/)

**Just to provide more info on `bind`**

Lets say me have an `object`:

```
var myObj = {};
```

And we assign a property to that `object`:

```
myObj.test_property = "Hello World!";
```

We can access that property from other properties through `bind` and `this`.

Lets say we make another property that's a `function`:

```
myObj.test_func = function()
{
    alert(this.test_property);
}.bind(myObj);
```

Wait do you guess this will do?

Because of the `bind` method, the scope of `this` was resolved to `myObj`.

Therefore, `this.test_property` is equal to `myObj.test_property`, retaining the scope.

Let's go further...

We'll declare another function:

```
myObj.test_func2 = function(val)
{
    this.test_property = val;
}.bind(myObj);
```

Now, lets run a test:

```
myObj.test_func();
myObj.test_func2("Hello Dude");
myObj.test_func();
```

As you can see, both `test_func` and `test_func2` share the same scope.

[**Here's a JSFiddle illustrating everything I've said about `bind`**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6u6bcyb/3/)

Comment: Also very helpful thanks.  Between you and Pavel I see 3 ways to do it.  Funny, I think seeing all three methods in reading had confused me to the point that I was mix and matching as Alnitak pointed out.  Although I hadn't tried the bind method.  Now I need to understand the pros and cons of each method.  :)

Comment: I thought that this. inside of the test_func() would resolve to anything in the function...  I thought that was a closure and this references anything inside that closure.  I guess that is incorrect.  I'm confused as to knowing where this points.

Comment: In my example, `this` will resolve to whatever the function was bound to, in this case, `this` will resolve to `myObj`. Within the function `myObj.test_func`, `this.test_func` would be a reference to itself.

Comment: Theres more too. Say I have two functions: `myObj.test_func1` and `myObj.test_func2`. Ahh.. I'll just update my anser to explain that too.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  This thread is a lightbulb for me. thanks all

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
new PersonClass()
```

at first time, prototype methods are created.

When you call

```
new PersonClass()
```

second time, **prototype methods are replaced** and now they has **last _this** in closure scope.

So, move prototype methods outside constructor function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sday/w20rtmqn/    I did it with the first GetAge that has the _this reference but nothing changed.  PersonClass.prototype.getAge=GetAge;   // then declare a separate function.  (is that what you meant?)

Comment: @sday First way: http://jsfiddle.net/w20rtmqn/2/. Second way: http://jsfiddle.net/w20rtmqn/3/. Dont modify constructor prototype inside constructor.

Comment: Very helpful thanks.  I have a feeling there is a follow up question with accessing this class through a click listener.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

1. `_this=this;`

   Creates a global variable `window._this`.
    Use a tools like jshint to avoid this kind of bugs.
2. `PersonClass.prototype` should not be used in a constructor function. You're mixing two different object creation patterns. Inside a construction function you should use something like

   `this.getAge2 = function(){...}`
3. Not necessarily a bug, but for your sample code binding this to _this is not required. This will only used when your function is not invoked on the object you've created, for example, using something like `window.setTimeout(john.getAge, 100)`

   This causes the getAge function to become unbound from the john object when invoked.

Here's your code with the discussed changes (that is not to say that I recommend this pattern):

```
var PersonClass = function PersonClass(_name, _age) {
    var _this=this;
    this.name=_name;
    this.age=_age;

    console.log("created "+this.name+":"+this.age);

    function changeAge(num) {
        console.log("changing age for:" + _this.name);
        _this.age=num;
    }

    this.changeAge=changeAge;
    this.getAge=function() { 
        console.log(_this.name+":"+_this.age);
        return _this.age;
    };
    this.getAge2=function() { 
        console.log(this.name+":"+this.age);        
        return this.age;
    };
};


var john=new PersonClass("john",1);  // john:1
var sue=new PersonClass("sue",2);    // sue:2

john.getAge(); // john:1
john.getAge2(); // john:1

john.changeAge(10); // john
sue.getAge(); // sue:2
sue.getAge2(); // sue:2
john.getAge(); // john:10
john.getAge2(); // john:10


window.setTimeout(john.getAge, 200); //john:10
window.setTimeout(john.getAge2, 400); // incorrect
```

Comment: Hahaha, a timeout **will not** fix this

Comment: @WebWanderer Timeout is not used to fix anything. 
It is used as a test case to demonstrate getAge works unbound to the object, and getAge2() doesn't.

Comment: Thanks.  This all started from larger code where a click event is causing all kinds of havoc.  The detachment as you say.  This thread although only minutes old has helped me immensely even tough I've read countless other threads on the subject.  I guess the immersion made the difference.

Comment: @Amitay - exactly why you see the two getAge() functions.  Me trying to understand why I couldn't get this to work with a click handler.  I'm betting armed with the knowledge from this thread I'll be successful.