# What is the fastest class/object access/instantiation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

While exploring a few different ways to build classes, I am curious as to what is the fastest way to instantiate and access classes.  Based on input from another question:

[Javascript scope and self=this, _this=this, that=this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925977/javascript-scope-and-self-this-this-this-that-this),

I am now looking at three methods for creating a class and curious what input is out there for the fastest way to create and access objects.

```
var DogClass = function DogClass(_age) {
    this.age=_age;

    this.setAge = function(num) {
        this.age=num;
    }.bind(this);    

    this.getAge = function() {
        return this.age;
    }.bind(this);    
};

var BirdClass = function BirdClass(_age) {
    var _this=this;
    this.age=_age;

    this.setAge = function(num) {
        _this.age=num;
    };    

    this.getAge = function() {
        return _this.age;
    };    
};

var CatClass = function CatClass(_age) {
    this.age=_age;
};

CatClass.prototype.setAge = function (num) {
    this.age=num;
};
CatClass.prototype.getAge = function () {
    return this.age;
};

function profileCreate() {
    console.log("Creating a million of each");

    var o,i,iterations=1000000;

    console.time('createDog');
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        o=new DogClass(4);    
    }
    console.timeEnd('createDog');

    console.time('createCat');
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        o=new CatClass(4);    
    }
    console.timeEnd('createCat');

    console.time('createBird');
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        o=new BirdClass(4);    
    }
    console.timeEnd('createBird');
}

function profileAccess() {
    console.log("Accessing a million of each");

    var o,i,iterations=1000000;

    console.time('accessDog');
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        fido.setAge(5);
    }
    console.timeEnd('accessDog');

    console.time('accessCat');
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        fluffy.setAge(6);
    }
    console.timeEnd('accessCat');

    console.time('accessBird');
    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        tweety.setAge(7);
    }
    console.timeEnd('accessBird');
}
```

Creating a million of each

- createDog: 1531.654ms
- createCat: 7.301ms
- createBird: 605.982ms

Accessing a million of each

- accessDog: 197.338ms
- accessCat: 11.404ms
- accessBird: 7.031ms

If I select the "profile access" button a second time, the accessCat method is much faster.

- accessDog: 185.607ms
- accessCat: 0.958ms
- accessBird: 11.095ms

???  Is the interpreter optimizing the calls due to a static number being passed?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sday/yrropeer/3/

Any thoughts on what errors I might have in the code to invalidate this mini performance test?  Seems to me the prototype is the fastest for creating classes, and the BirdClass is the fastest for access.

Comment: You should not be using performance as a primary criterion for selecting a pattern given that it is likely insignificant in the overall scheme of things. Consider things that actually matter.

Comment: @RobG - I disagree with your statement. Performance may be my biggest concern and this thread was to understand and evaluate performance so that I can weigh that against what type of functionality I need. I may need certain objects to be performant and others robust in functionality.

Comment: Rudimentary analysis will indicate that creating instances of *CatClass* is likely much faster than the other two (though such analysis should be backed up by evidence) and that creating *DogClass* will be slower. Also, your "access" test is flawed, you aren't just accessing a property, you're calling a method, which has significantly more overhead in the two non–prototype methods as they must maintain closures and more complex scope chains. But they also have features not available in the prototype example, it's the features that matter most unless you have a specific example otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There are many design patterns in order to create class, objects and each one has its own pros ans cons. in order to compare them look at [this](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

Comment: Looks like some excellent reading although I didn't see anything jump out at me with respect to evaluating the performance of each.  Thanks for the link